# Best practice to deploy multi stacks in cloudFormation using codepipeline

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

I have a repository in CodeCommit, and in this repository, there are 3 branches dev, stage, and prod, in this repository there are multi stacks versioned, for example:

root/

--task-1

----template.yml

------src

--------index.js

--------package.json

--task-2

--task-3

--task-....

--buildspec.yml

Where every folder contains a different template yml and its src folder for the specific Lamba code, the buildspec.yml contains the commands to enter in every task folder and execute the required commands to install the node packages required and the sam or cloudformation commands to create or update the stack.

When a new commit is pushed to origins this trigger the pipeline and executes all the commands of buildspec.yml and create/update all the stacks even when only one stack has been changed in the code, here the question if there are better solutions to handle multi stacks in one repository and one pipeline.

One idea is to create one repository and pipeline for each stack in this way every stack will be updated independently of the other stacks, but in this way, if there are 20 stacks will be required 20 repositories and 20 pipelines.

I would like to know what is the best practice to handle multi stacks in the same repository and one pipeline and avoid deploying all the stacks when just one stack has been updated, or update only stacks that were updated in codecommit.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Amazon EventBridge (Amazon CloudWatch Events) rule that invokes an AWS Lambda function to evaluate changes to the repository and run the appropriate pipeline.

it could be fixed using a lambda and event bridge when a commit happens, more details https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/devops/adding-custom-logic-to-aws-codepipeline-with-aws-lambda-and-amazon-cloudwatch-events/